# How can I remove my sink drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

I'm trying to replace the second of two sink drains. The first went smoothly, but I'm stymied by the second, which is of course a completely different product.

I have the trap off and everything unscrewed, but I can't lift the assembly from the top because of that protruding flange where the drain lever attached.

Is there a junction I'm supposed to unscrew somewhere at the top? The brass nut that held the assembly against the bottom of the sink doesn't go any further down, so I can only lift the assembly about 1/2".

[image: Picture of a drain assembly underneath a sink]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to unscrew the upper part of the drain, the part that's in the basin where your stopper is located, from the tailpiece.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was totally it.  I wasn't aware that unscrewed.  I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHIyHlnj9Vw) that helped clear things up.

Comment: More than glad to help.